# Meaning of $P(X \in A)$

Tags: probability

I have the following problem. I'm struggling a little bit with the expression $P(X \in A)$. My problem is that $A$ is a set, whereas $X$ is a function. I can not really related this two items.

Here are some related definitions from the textbook I use.

- Sample space: $\Omega$
- Outcome: $\omega$
- Event: $A, (A \subset \Omega) $
- Random variable:  $X: \Omega \rightarrow R $ $\big($X assigns a real number to each outcome ($X(\omega)$ $\big)$.

I tried to work out a simple example: Toss a coin two times and let X be the number of heads. Then: $\Omega = \{HH,HT,TH,TT\} $. For example if we have a look on the prob. that we get two heads, $P(X=2)=\frac{|\{HH\}|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{1}{4}$, it makes kind of sense to me, because we compare the cardinality of of two sets. However, I can not imagine a Example of $P(X \in A)$.

Can maybe someone give some intuition for that or give a small example in the case of a coin toss (or dice or ...).

cheers!

Comment: This is a notation: $\mathbb{P}\{X\in A\} = \mathbb{P}( X^{-1}(A))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(X \in A)$ is just a shorthand notation for the expression $P(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \in A\})$.

Comment: Ok! I just don't really understand the notation. I mean it is kind of the same problem that I have, because I see X as a function and A as a set. In the second expression $X(\omega)$ is a real number and A is a set, right ?!. Let's say A is the event of the first toss is head, then $A=\{ HH,HT \}$ and $X(\omega)$ of some outcome will be number like 1 or 2. Sorry, maybe my question is a little bit trivial, but I just don't see the picture here. @Clement C.

Comment: In the case of real-valued random variables, $A$ is a subset of the real numbers; It is not an event in $\Omega$. You could ask for the probability that there was exactly one head in the coin tosses. This would be $P(X \in \{1\}) = P(\{HT, TH\})$.

Answer (score 1):

$X \in A$ is shorthand for $\{\omega: X(\omega) \in A\}$.  Probabilists tend to avoid mentioning the sample point $\omega$ whenever possible.  You should get used to this.

Answer (score 0):

In the coin toss case, you could think of $A$ as just being some subset of the sample space, e.g. $A=\{HH,TH,HT\}$.

Situations where this type of probability is a little more prevalent (and, arguably, natural) include random processes like random walks. If $X_n$ is a random walk on, say, $\mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathbb{P}(X_n\in\{-1,0,1\}])$ would be the probability of the particle being within $1$ unit of the origin after $n$ steps. In more complex cases (e.g. 2D Brownian motion), $A$ could be any (possibly more complicated) subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $\mathbb{P}(X_t\in A)$ is the probability of the particle being in the set $A$ at time $t$.